# Stand-Alone Sentry-like Logger for Django 1.4+

Tags: django, logging, sentry

I have a number of projects that used the older, stand-alone version of [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) but it no longer works when I update the projects to Django 1.5 because of template incompatibilities and some other things I haven't been able to correct. As far as I can tell, the newer versions of Sentry either want you to subscribe or to set it up as a web service (instead of just using it as a package in your Django project). I really don't want to do that but I really do like the functionality. Is there something I can use to replace this or is there still a way to integrate directly into a Django project so admin users are shared, etc.